# Take values from cells in column of one excel table and check if this values exist in column of other excel table

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Here is the code and I am stuck here. I would like to do the function which I described below the code. I need your help. Thanks!

**EDIT at 16.11.2021:** I wrote my solution and share it with you:

```
import pandas as pd

# column selection
table_one_cols = [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 17, 21]
table_two_cols = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]

data_one = pd.read_excel('table_one.xlsx', skiprows=2, usecols=table_one_cols, index_col=0)
data_two = pd.read_excel('table_two.xlsx', usecols=table_two_cols, index_col=0)

# combine_type = inner, left, right, outer (check this types in internet)
# FristColumnName - you can write the name of column which you want to compare in both tables
df = pd.merge(data_one, data_two, on='FristColumnName', how='outer')

df = df.rename(columns={"Column 1 Old Name": "Column 2 New Name"})

print(df.columns)

# save output to new file
df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

**=============================================**

```
import openpyxl as xl

dict_store = {}

# opening the head excel file
data1 = "D:\\data1.xlsx"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(data1)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

# opening the second excel file
data2 = "D:\\data2.xlsx"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(data2)
ws2 = wb2.active

# calculate total number of rows
data1_max_row = ws1.max_row
data2_max_row = ws2.max_row

# I created this func to store the values of head table in dict (I don't know if that's right)
def create_dict():
    for i in range(1, data1_max_row):
        dict_store[i] = ws1.cell(i, 1).value

    # for j in dict.values():
    # print(j)


def check_cells():
    for i in range(1, data2_max_row):
        for j in dict_store.values():
            if i == j:
                print("true")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_dict()
    check_cells()
```

**I have a table with 2 columns:**

```
Column 1   Column 2
a          f
b          g
c          h
d          i
e          j
```

**I have and a second table with 2 columns:**

```
Column 1   Column 2
a          a
x          b
e          c
```

So, I want to check if rows in column 1 of second table are existing in first table in column 1. If yes -> copy the value of other column(column 2) into a new column 3(with some header name) to second table, at the same row. If not -> row stays empty.

Example for understanding better:
**a** and **e** from second table are existing in table 1, column 1, but they are not in a row. I mean they are mixed. So, that what needs to happen now with the second table is adding a third column:

**Result which I except:**

```
Column 1   Column 2   Column 3
a          a          f (taked from column 2 in table 1)
x          b          this row stays empty, beacuse x doesn't exist there
e          c          j (taked value from column 2 in table 1)
```

I hope you understood me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use vlookup
Don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: I read some topics related with this function, but cannot implement in my code for my needs as it is a question of two separate files, instead of two separate tables, also with more columns which I want to choose, not just to merge everything.

Comment: I wrote a solution for my question. You can check it in my description of problem.